# "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" - how to put list item into a matrix

Tags: python, split

I want to place items from a parsed string into a 2D matrix.

I'm new to python and I don't really understand what my problem is.  Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

```
import os
import sys

Stage_Schedule = open('C:\\Users\\Reid.Cytron\\Desktop\\11LA_9LA_Schedule.txt', 'r')
lines = Stage_Schedule.readlines()

Well_Schedule = [[0 for x in range(136)] for y in range(4)]

i = 1
for line in lines:
    txt = line.split("\t")

    print(str(txt[0]) + '\t' + txt[1])

    Well_Schedule[i, 0] = txt[0]  # This is the line where the error occurs

    i = i + 1

Stage_Schedule.close()
```

When I run the code I get the following error message.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

The notation you're using is only supported for Numpy arrays. This is the correct way to index a nested list in Python:

```
Well_Schedule[i][0] = txt[0]
```

Comment: It worked.  That was embarrassing.  Thank you for your help!